# Office 2013 save to SharePoint Team site instead of my-site

Tags: 2013, office-365, office, team-sites

When I use Word 2013 and I click save, I have the option of saving to my organization's SharePoint site. However as soon as I click save, and chose SharePoint, I'm prompted to MySite. By clicking on the URL and editing it, I am able to browse to the main Site, and navigate from there. The UI in the window for saving, is nicely organized.

I know I can map this to a network drive, but the end result is not as nice! For me it's not a big deal editing the URL or using this structure but for the rest of the employees, is not doable.

So my question is, **how can I setup office to directly open the Team Site** rather than MySite?

Comment: Is this still an issue or have you find a solution that worked for you? If so, please post as an answer

Comment: Still an issue and i have not found a way to do this! it's ridiculous :?

Answer (score 3):

If you have connected the SharePoint Document library to Office using the *Connect to Office* button - it will show up as an option in your recent view of Office.

[image]

But the best option IMHO is to teach users not to start Word and then save, but do it the other way around. Let them learn how to create a new file from the document library where they want to save the document. Word will open (if you have set up the library to do so) and when your users hit save, the correct dialog location will show up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The good part is that you now have this SharePoint library available in the Recent Folders of SharePoint, even if your users start Word as application and not from a list.

[image]

And your users can navigate SharePoint in the Save As dialog

[image]

I agree to that this isn't the best User Experience users can have, but it works. And the more libraries they connect to, the better there Recent Folders list will be.